# How to find the value of a column A where the value of column B is the min value for B

Tags: sql, jpql

I have a table like this

```
|---------------------------|
|     A      |       B      |
|---------------------------|
|     1      |       5      |
|     2      |       7      |
|     3      |      12      |
|     4      |     100      |
|     5      |       0      |
|     6      |       2      |
|     7      |       5      |
|---------------------------|
```

What would be the SQL query or JPQL query that returns the value of A in the row where B has min value (or eventually all the rows have the same min value)?

In this examplethe query should return 5 or the whole entity that corresponds to the row with A = 5 in case of JPA.

Comment: I see no search effort

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a from your_table
where b = (select min(b) from your_table)
```